# Excepción de Formatos en Java

Tags: java, excepciones, try-catch

Estoy realizando un ejercicio, en el cual una de las partes pide insertar una temporada de tipo `String`. **Pero si no es de un formato especifico, salte un error.**

Este seria el formato que debe de aceptar: `01/02` (Los números dan igual).

¿Como podría personalizar este error, o hay alguno que me pueda servir?

Este seria el código:

```
        System.out.print("Indicame el ID del juagador:");
        id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Indicame la temporada: ");
        temporada = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Indicame los puntos por partido: ");
        puntosPartido = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Indicame los rebotes por partido:");
        rebotesPartido = sc.nextFloat();

        //CREO LAS INSTANCIAS DE ESTADISTICAS:
        Estadisticas estadisticas = new Estadisticas();
        EstadisticasId estadisticasID = new EstadisticasId(temporada, id);

        //AGREGO LOS DATOS A LAS ESTADISTICAS:          
        estadisticas.setId(estadisticasID);
        estadisticas.setPuntosPorPartido(puntosPartido);
        estadisticas.setRebotesPorPartido(rebotesPartido);
        estadisticas.setAsistenciasPorPartido(0.0F);
        estadisticas.setTaponesPorPartido(0.0F);

        //GUARDO LA SESION:
        sesion.save(estadisticas);

        //REALIZO LOS CAMBIOS A LA BBDD:
        trans.commit();

        System.out.println("!Insertado!");

    }catch(PersistenceException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }catch(NumberFormatException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

La cosa es que no se como "invalidar" todo lo que se escriba a no ser que sea ese formato.

Comment: Podrías usar una expresion regular, en tu caso para un valor dd/mm tendrias que utilizar ^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))$

Comment: ¿Como seria en el código? Nunca he usado expresiones regulares para ser sincero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero deberíamos crear una Exception custom para el caso de tener un formato de temporada erróneo:

```
public class FormatException extends RuntimeException {

    public FormatException (String message) { super(message); }

    public FormatException (){ super(); }
}
```

Luego podríamos jugar con la lógica en nuestro código para lanzarla cuando corresponda, es aquí donde usaremos una **expresion regular** (Regex) para validar el formato de la temporada a tipo **dd/mm**:

```
//Se importa el paquete java.util.regex
import java.util.regex.*;

//Obtenemos un Pattern con la expresión regular.
Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0- 
2]))$");   

System.out.print("Indicame la temporada: ");
temporada = sc.next();
Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(temporada);
// Hace que Matcher busque los trozos.
if( !matcher.find()) {
    throw new FormatException(); 
}
```

En caso de NO cumplirse la regex se lanzaría la exception, de lo contrario la aplicación continuaría su flujo normal.